# Converting cv::mat to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt5

like the title says I am trying to convert a cv::mat to a QImage. What I am doing is using the equalizeHist() function on the mat and then converting it to a QImage to display in widget window in Qt. I know the mat works and loads the image correctly because the equalized image will show in the new window with imshow(), however when converting this mat to a QImage, I can not get it to display in the window. I believe the problem is with the conversion from the mat to QImage but cant find the issue. Below is a part of my code snippet.

```
Mat image2= imread(directoryImage1.toStdString(),0);
//cv::cvtColor(image2,image2,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat histEquImg;
equalizeHist(image2,histEquImg);
imshow("Histogram Equalized Image 2", histEquImg);
//QImage img=QImage((uchar*) histEquImg.data, histEquImg.cols, histEquImg.rows, histEquImg.step, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
imageObject= new QImage((uchar*) histEquImg.data, histEquImg.cols, histEquImg.rows, histEquImg.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
image = QPixmap::fromImage(*imageObject);
scene=new QGraphicsScene(this); //create a frame for image 2
scene->addPixmap(image); //put image 1 inside of the frame
ui->graphicsView_4->setScene(scene); //put the frame, which contains image 3, to the GUI
ui->graphicsView_4->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio); //keep the dimension ratio of image 3
```

No errors occur and the program doesnt crash.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Edit: tried adding in the cv::cvtColor back to change the output histogram image. Still nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the conversion of the QImage to `cv::Mat`, when using the flag 0 in `cv::imread` implies the reading is grayscale, and you are using the conversion with the format `QImage::Format_RGB88`8. I use the following function to make the conversion of `cv::Mat` to `QImage`:

```
static QImage MatToQImage(const cv::Mat& mat)
{
    // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=1
    if(mat.type()==CV_8UC1)
    {
        // Set the color table (used to translate colour indexes to qRgb values)
        QVector<QRgb> colorTable;
        for (int i=0; i<256; i++)
            colorTable.push_back(qRgb(i,i,i));
        // Copy input Mat
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
        // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
        img.setColorTable(colorTable);
        return img;
    }
    // 8-bits unsigned, NO. OF CHANNELS=3
    if(mat.type()==CV_8UC3)
    {
        // Copy input Mat
        const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
        // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
        QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        return img.rgbSwapped();
    }
    return QImage();
}
```

After that I see that you have misconceptions of how `QGraphicsView` and `QGraphicsScene` work when commenting: *put the frame, which contains image 3, to the GUI*, with `ui->graphicsView_4->setScene(scene);` you are not setting a frame but a scene, and the scene should only be set once and preferably in the constructor.

```
// constructor
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

So when you want to load the image just use the scene:

```
cv::Mat image= cv::imread(filename.toStdString(), CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

cv::Mat histEquImg;
equalizeHist(image, histEquImg);

QImage qimage = MatToQImage(histEquImg);
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(qimage);
scene->addPixmap(pixmap);
ui->graphicsView->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

<sup>The complete example can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/52583391).</sup>

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! First time using Qt so I have a lot more to learn.